# SharePoint - DNS not responding after enabling AD

Tags: sharepoint, dns, sharepoint-2013

I set up a Server 2012 VM in Hyper-V, and had internet access working with a virtual switch.  I'm following this tutorial:

http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/10/create-a-scripted-sharepoint-2013-development-environment-tutorial-part-1.html

And I've gotten to the point where the tutorial says

> (You can now add your internet connection for the rest of the tutorial
>   )!

My internet connection no longer works and if I ping external addresses, I get no response.  If I troubleshoot network issues I see that "The DNS server is not responding".  I have a static IP address set up and the DNS in ipV4 is set to `127.0.0.1`.  How can I re-enable connectivity to my external connection from the vm?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. This is a server configuration issue. Try serverfault or superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two network cards right? One "private" for your AD/DC/DNS, and another one that should be External that you should enable when you get at that point in the tutorial! On the private you should have a fixed ip with DNS of 127.0.0.1 while on the External you can probably go with your router DHCP!

Comment: Thanks Vlad.  I only have one External Virtual Network Switch in hyper-v... do I need to add another, or are you talking about something else?

Comment: @RobVious You need to have at least 2 network cards attached to your VM. One private and one External!